# Access value in object with . in it's name

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, express

So I'm playing around with creating a Facebook chatbot. In order to talk to Facebook I need to validate I have ownership of the URL I give Facebook in the Webhooks panel.

I have an express route that looks like

```
app.get('/api/verification', (req, res) => {
  // Send back hub.challenge
});
```

So in the `req` object I get back from Facebook it looks like:

```
{ 'hub.mode': 'subscribe',
   'hub.challenge': '178462834',
   'hub.verify_token': 'my_verify_token' }
```

In order to get to this I `console.log` out `req.query` and get this back. But I can't then go `req.query.hub.challenge` because I'll get `undefined` since `hub.challenge` is the value name.

How do I access the value if it's got a . in it's name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `req.query['hub.challenge']`

More information on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: Thanks dude :) Yeah this was it. Amateur hour here :p